# Bootstrap 4 Custom Forms are not clickable in popover

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, frontend

In bootstrap 4, only custom forms are not clickable in bootstrap popover.

So weird that default forms of bootstrap 4 are working properly.

How can I fix it?

This below contains my code, and Thank you for your help.

`JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2asy9Lgc/1/`

Comment: Post the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.custom-control-input {

    z-index: 3;
  
}
```

change that z-index:-1;

Comment: Oh my god It works well! Thank u :)